# File is showing instead of download

Tags: apache, download, mamp-pro

When I download file, it is not downloaded and it shows in browser.
zip file is downloaded. this say server is working,
 but when i try with ipa file(the extension of file is ipa), it shows content of file in browser instead of downloading.
I am using mamp.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set a Content-Disposition header for this file - please see more information on [MDN Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition). This way the server indicates that the file is an attachment and should be saved on the disk.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg"
```

The *filename* parameter is not mandatory. However, it'll suggest the name of the file.

On the other hand, if you have a HTML5 page with an anchor tag you may want to use *download* attribute, e.g.:

```
<a href="filename.jpg" download="filename.jpg">
```

The problem with *download* attribute is - it's not supported by all of the major browsers - see [download attribute support](http://caniuse.com/#search=download). There is still a lack of support from the IE, iOS and Opera mini.

Comment: Thank you Mateusz Kleinert. I am not working with html, php, atachement. My files are in folder of document root, just i want to download files

Comment: Then add Content-Disposition in your Apache's configuration.

Comment: it's not working, have you been used mamp before and seen this error?

Comment: I've been using an Apache for quite a long time. Anyway, this is not an error. This is your browser setting. You may try to suggest the browser to download the file instead of opening it by adding a correct header. The second option is to change the browser settings (set which files should be opened and which should be saved on the disk). As an alternative you may want to set the header: Content-Type: application/octet-stream for all of your files. However, there are some drawbacks of this solution.

Comment: i added application/octet-stream, and it is working, but i can't see the file size and download progressing, is there any solution?

Comment: application/octet-stream stands for arbitrary binary data. The size of the file should be determined by the Content-Length header.

Comment: <Files *.ipa>
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files> this is what i have added, it was working well, but i couldn't know the file size and duration

Comment: Then you should also set the size of the file. Look at the "Content Disposition Parameters" described under this URL: https://www.iana.org/assignments/cont-disp/cont-disp.xhtml
It will look like this (you need to specify the size for the file): <Files *.ipa> Header set Content-Disposition attachment; size=1000 </Files>